# TFS project sharing issue

Tags: android, eclipse, tfs

While sharing project into TFS from my eclipse,it returns following error

> Error Setting working folder: Could not rename properties.tf2 to properties.tf1 in recover.

I am using following things,

> Windows 7 PC, Eclipse Juno IDE, ADT version 23.0.2.1259578, TFS plugin
>   for Eclipse 11.0.0.201306181529

How to solve that issue ?

Answer (score 1):

This is old thread but I will answer it for others: If you have encountered this problem try to RUN eclipse as administrator. it will solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Go to C:/ProgramData/Microsoft Team Foundation Local Workspaces/.../... and delete or rename 'properties.tf1'. Try sharing the project again.

Comment: I had deleted that properties.tf1 file, now also it shows the same error :(

Comment: thanks this really helped .I was getting the below error in my eclipse "Error querying for item: Could not rename local version.tf2 to local version.tf1 in recovery"